# Closure under union function in Haskell

Tags: function, haskell

So I tried to make a function that takes a collection of list and returns true is that collection is closed under union or not.

```
closureUnderUnion :: [[String]] -> Bool
closureUnderUnion mp =
  all (\i -> all (\j -> union i j `elem` mp) mp) mp
```

But for

```
closureUnderUnion [[],["a","b","c"],["a"],["b", "c"]]
```

Returns False

Comment: You should specify what goes wrong here: compiler error, runtime error, wrong result, etc. Anyway, the idea looks correct, but I'd guess that the issue is that `elem` checks for exact equality, while `union i j` might produce a list with the elements in a different order (and possibly different multiplicity?). ``["a", "b"] `elem` [["b", "a"], [], ...]`` is false, for instance. Maybe you need to write your own variant of `elem` that ignores order/multiplicity.

Comment: If you are working with set-like objects (from the question it seems you are working with topological spaces), you should use `Data.Set` from the `containers` package. As @chi commented the all these are different list `["a", "b"] /= ["b","a"] /= ["a","b","a"]` but they are the same set.

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that union does not guarantee to return a sorted list:

```
ghci> union ["b"] ["a"]
["b","a"]
```

So you'd need to use a different kind of equality:

```
newtype SetList a = SetList [a]

instance Eq a => Eq (SetList a) where
  SetList xs == SetList ys = 
     all (`elem` ys) xs && all (`elem` xs) ys

closureUnderUnion :: [[String]] -> Bool
closureUnderUnion mp =
  all (\i -> all (\j -> SetList (union i j) `elem` map SetList mp) mp) mp
```

If your elements do have an `Ord` instance like `[String]` does in your case then the best solution then is to use a data structure that is optimised for set operations:

```
import qualified Data.Set as Set
import Data.Set (Set)

closureUnderUnion :: Set (Set String) -> Bool
closureUnderUnion mp =
  all (\i -> all (\j -> Set.union i j `Set.member` mp) mp) mp
```

Comment: FTR, ``all (`elem` ys) xs && all (`elem` xs) ys`` is brutally inefficient for an equality check.

Comment: @leftaroundabout O(n^2) seems optimal if you don't have `Ord`. If you do have `Ord` then the answer is of course to just use `Data.Set`.

Comment: Yes. Lists with a sorting smart constructor or `SetList xs==SetList ys = sort xs==sort ys` would also work.

Comment: Is `i >= j` really enough? e.g. `union "ac" "b"` is `"acb"`, which still isn't in sorted order. Perhaps ```\j -> sort (union i j) `elem` mp``` would be a better choice.

Comment: @DanielWagner good point, I've removed that part.